# Java - creating a custom event with buttons and mouseclicks

Tags: java, events

I am trying to create a custom event which listens and responses to the clicks of a button. The button is represented as an oval, drawn in a paintComponent method on shown in a JFrame. When it is clicked, it is supposed to change colour, then return to a previous colour when clicked again - like an ON / OFF button.

I have created an interface for it:

```
public interface gListener {
    public void gActionPerformed(GooEvent e);
}
```

An event listener:

```
public class gEvent extends java.util.EventObject
{
    private int x, y;
    private int value;
    private gComponent source;
    final static int ON = 1;
    final static int OFF = 0;

public gEvent(int x, int y, int val, gComponent source)
{
    super(source);
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    value = val;
    this.source = source;
}
}
```

A component class to represent the button:

```
public abstract class gComponent {

    //Link an arraylist to the gListener interface.
    ArrayList <gListener> listeners = new ArrayList<gListener>();
    int x, y, w, h;

    public gComponent(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        this.x = x; this.y = y; this.w = w; this.h = h;
    }

//Add listener to arraylist
    public void addListener(gListener gl)
    {
        listeners.add(gl);
    }

    // Dispatches the gEvent e to all registered listeners.
    protected void send (gEvent e){
        e = new gEvent(x, y, w, this);
        Iterator<GooListener> i = listeners.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext())  
        {
            ((gListener) i.next()).gActionPerformed(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The gComponent class is extended in a button class (gButton), which is where the paintComponent and mouseClicked methods are called. And lastly... I have the test class which extends a JPanel and implements the gListener interface. The main method looks like the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // JFrame code goes here....


        gButton button = new gButton(20,20,20,20); //Click oval shape

          //Using addListener method from gComponent superclass.
          //The 'this' code is throwing error: cannot use this in a static context.
        button.addListener(this); 
}

  //Cause something to happen - stop/start animation.
    public void gooActionPerformed(GooEvent e){


    }
```

The event is suppose to trigger from a click of the button, in this particular format of how I have written the code.
Any advice to the error I received as stated in my test class, or anything else would be much appreciated.  Many thanks.

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply... breathtaking.

But in any case, there's no `this` in a static method like `main()`. If you want an object with a `gooActionPerformed()` method, then you need to create an instance of whatever class `main()` appears in, and use that instance in place of `this`.

Comment: Of course! Thank you for that. Any ideas of how to handle the mouse events that occur?

Comment: If you need to actually handle mouse clicks, you should just get rid of all of this and use the built-in AWT event mechanism.

Comment: I know, but the format of which I have designed the code is what is required. I am still trying to understand custom events; how would a custom event detect a mouse click? Can the java.util.EventObject do this?

Comment: There's no way to get real mouse clicks without using the actual AWT event mechanism. Is this some kind of crazy homework assignment? What's the actual assignment? If you really needed to to all this and connect it to actual mouse clicks, you'd need to also implement a real `MouseListener` or `ActionListener` and then forward the calls or events to your classes.

Comment: I thought so. You guessed correctly about this task at hand. I have about 6 classes which all communicate with each other to listen and response to a mouse click. This assignment is heavily object oriented in that every area is split up into its own class (i.e. buttons, components, interfaces, events, and the tester class). I appreciate the direction you have provided, as I now know that a MouseListener is required for the JPanel which the button is held in. Many thanks.